# Cannot modify tab settings in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I want tab to insert 2 spaces.  All other solutions seem to be references an older version of Qt Creator.

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Behaviour -> Tabs and Indentation

No 'Options' option exists in the dropdown menu.

> Tools -> Options -> C++ -> Code Styles -> Edit

'Code Styles' does NOT exist in that path.

> Qt Creator -> Preferences -> Behavior > Text Editor

This seems to be the appropriate place to modify settings for the whole IDE, but they don't seem to be getting saved to the project.

[image]
Qt 5.2.1

Comment: `Qt Creator > Preferences > Text Editor > Behavior > Tabs and Indentation`.

Comment: I was just updating to explain that I've tried that and it's not working either.

Comment: `Qt Creator > Preferences > C++ > Code Style > Copy..` or `Edit...`. Also ensure that the project you have uses the code style you selected.

Comment: screenshot included.  how can i validate the project uses that code style?

Comment: When you're coding, you're usually in Edit or Debug mode (they are two of the 6 or so large icons on the toolbar at the left). Switch to Projects and look at the tabs Editor and Code Style. Once you're sure of that, `Cmd+a` (select all in the file) and `Cmd+i` to reindent everything.

Comment: ah, that was it.  thanks.  much less straightforward than sublime text editor.  i needed to make a copy of the code style in order for my changes to be saved.

Comment: The instructions you were reading were most likely the Linux/Windows ones, which is why they directed you to look at Tools > Options. In general though in Mac OS X application preferences are always under 'Name of Application' > Preferences. Qt Creator allows you to have different coding styles for different projects, but the price to pay for that is that there's something like 3 different places to configure these things and even I don't understand how exactly they all tango.

Comment: iwillnotexist Idontexist. Please post comment as answer so that it can be accepted and upvoted

Comment: Adding a new `Code Style` doesn't seem to affect open documents (I'm changing this per-project). I had to close and re-open everything from the "Open Documents" window.

Answer (score 7):

There are "Project Settings" that have precedence over the global settings under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> ...
These settings can be found in the Projects "UI section" and you have to define a custom "Code Style" for this:

1. Switch to "Projects" (Ctrl-5)
2. From the column to the right select "Code Style" (not "Editor") under "Project Settings"
3. Click "Edit..."
4. Click "Copy Built-in Code Style"
5. On the "General" tab adjust tab settings

Comment: I don't see any "*Edit...*" button there though. Only Copy.../Remove/Export.../Import...

Comment: You need to check "Override .clang-format file".